# AS400 SQL query to determine records for who is 70.5 years old for the current year

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to find individuals that will turn 70.5 years old in the current year.

dob7 = DECIMAL(7)  YYYYDDD

```
select acctno, name, address, status, year(curdate()) - year(date(digits(dob7))) as Age
from mydata.cdmast cdmast
left join mydata.cfmast cfmast
on cdmast.cifno = cfmast.cifno
where status <> 'R' and year(curdate()) - year(date(digits(dob7))) >= 70
```

The code above returns the following error:

`[Error Code: -181, SQL State: 22008]  [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0181 - Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid`.

Comment: To be more accurate in responding to your exact request, do you mean that the person will turn 70.5 within 1 year after the current date, or do you mean within the current calendar year?  If the first option is what you are seeking, you could simply ask the question who is age 69.5 now.  But the next part is, do you wish to exclude those who have already turned 70.5, in other words are you seeking only those who will have the event of turning 70.5 during the year.

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the other answers, I'm submitting my own.  This should have the benefit of using any indicies on `dob7`, and should work without too many 'tricks'.

I've modified the `WHERE` clause in your original query.  I'm assuming '.5 years' means '6 months', although this is adjustable.  I deliberately wrapped the calculations in CTEs to 'encapsulate' the logic; the operations should be nearly no-cost.

```
WITH Youngest (dateOfBirth) as (
               SELECT CURRENT_DATE - 70 YEARS - 6 MONTHS
               FROM sysibm/sysdummy1),
     Converted (dateOfBirth, formatted) as (
                SELECT dateOfBirth, YEAR(dateOfBirth) * 1000 + DAYOFYEAR(dateOfBirth)
                FROM Youngest)
SELECT acctno, name, address, status, 
       YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - INT(dob7 / 1000) 
                          - CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR(CURRENT_DATE) < MOD(dbo7, 1000)
                                 THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0 END as Age
FROM myData.cdMast cdMast
JOIN Converted
ON Converted.formatted >= dob7
LEFT JOIN myData.cfMast cfMast
ON cdMast.cifno = cfMast.cifno
WHERE status <> 'R'
```

Please note that it will consider people born on a leap day to have had their birthday on March 1st (due to `DAYOFYEAR()`).

Answer (score 1):

From the [DATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadate.htm) scalar function documentation:

> A string with an actual length of 7 that represents a valid date in the form *yyyynnn*, where *yyyy* are digits denoting a year, and *nnn* are digits between 001 and 366 denoting a day of that year.

Reformat the date with:

```
DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),4,4) || SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),1,3))
```

To select 70.5 or older by the end of the current year:

```
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),4,4) || SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),1,3))) = 70
AND MONTH(DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),4,4) || SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),1,3))) >= 6
OR YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(DATE(SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),4,4) || SUBSTR(DIGITS(DOB7),1,3))) > 70
```

Comment: Ouch... I think I'd rather just convert `CURRENT_DATE` to the numeric form, which would let me use any indicies on the column (since it _is_ in a nicely sortable format).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
(year(curdate()) - mod(dob7, 10000)) >= 70
```

This is using modular arithmetic to extract the year, rather than trying to convert it to a date.

By the way, storing the date this way seems very awkward.  Databases have built-in support for dates and times, so it is usually better to store them in the native format.

If you date of birth is really yyyymmm, then the following should work for years:

```
(year(curdate()) - cast(dob7/1000 as int)) >= 70
```

For the half year:

```
(year(curdate()) - cast(dob7/1000 as int))+(1-mod(dob7,1000)/365.0) >= 70.5
```

Comment: This is returning all ages not just > 70.  I am needing to only select those that will turn 70.7 in 2012.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a dob7 looks like?

Comment: Sample of dob7 is 1960002  1/2/1960
When I execute the query without the second portion of the where statement the proper select results are returned.  The issue comes when I try and limit the age to 70.5.

Comment: I cannot think of a good reason why it would work in the select but not the where.  Evaluation order is one possibility; put in parentheses to be sure things are evaluated in order.  Have you checked if anyone is, indeed, in this age range?

Comment: Just tried 
    where (year(curdate()) - mod(dob7, 10000) > 70.5)

Comment: @macunte - Your data doesn't match the original format you've provided  in the question (it would actually match `'yyyyddd'` - pretty much a julian date format).  Gordon - I'm thinking it should be possible to convert the current date into an integer in this format, to use index access.

Comment: Just tried 
    where (year(curdate()) - mod(dob7, 10000) > 70.5)
    where year(curdate()) - mod(dob7, 10000) > 70.5
each appeared to be ignored.  There are 14 records that qualify.

Comment: Gordon - you're still missing the '.5' bit.  Besides which, you'd have to cast the result of `dob7/1000` to `INT`, as (at least on my box) it's promoting it to floating-point.  This should be do-able through manipulating `CURRENT_DATE` to a numeric format, though the OP may not need to, depending on what's executing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the contents of DOB7 cannot be converted to a date.  Does the value of DOB7 match one of the valid formats?  Note that many require quotation marks.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzscadate.htm